# Wrong JVM version for Jira

Tags: linux, jvm, jira

The problem appears on Linux CentOS 7 server. The service jira will start | stop but when I try to run config.sh I get an error, check-java.sh gives the same error .

The error reads like this:

No JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable is set - attempting to just run java command

---

**********     Wrong JVM version! You are running with .. but JIRA requires at least 1.8 to run.      **********

---

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

When Running `alternatives --config java` I get the following:

```
    There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

### The solutions tried were:

Modified /etc/environment JAVA_HOME to suit the location of java from jira's default setenv.sh location `JAVA_HOME="/opt/atlassian/jira/jre/"; export JAVA_HOME`. This solution makes `service jira start | stop` stop working.

Modified /etc/environment blindly to use every folder from `/usr/lib/jvm`

```
java
java-1.8.0
java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64
java-openjdk
jre
jre-1.8.0
jre-1.8.0-openjdk
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64
jre-openjdk
```

Tried to update Java but `Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`.

Comment: Where you quote the error : ' Wrong JVM version! You are running with ..' what's the version it believes it is running?

Comment: I did not find any indication of that, it is just saying that, just that. Nowhere did I find a different version. @Kerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the problem is comes like this.

1. Use the path `JAVA_HOME="/opt/atlassian/jira/jre/"` in `/etc/environment`

   Command `source /etc/environment` to update the PATH

   Do your business.

Answer (score 0):

If to edit 'check-java.sh' file as follows:

```
java_version=14

echo $java_version

if [ $java_version -ne 8 ] && [ $java_version -ne 11 ] && [ $java_version -ne 14 ]
then
```

Jira v.8.4.1 is available for computations for Apple macOS Mojave 10.14.6 as in the local early access experiment for Java 14-ea.

After each update event of Jira version OR update event of Java JVM version (in case of update by substituting the whole either software folder) 'check-java.sh' file is better to be updated in those cases as well (also for automation scripts).

This approach with hard coding of the JVM version value for Jira script allows to run Jira version (at least 8.4.1) via newer JVM versions in experimental mode and along with other software as well at single JVM not only limited by and supported by 1.8 or 11 JVM versions without need to install and to maintain two several JVM versions (in case of folder installations) in experimental mode, if other software can use newer JVM, so more Jira data backups are better to apply in small data scoped setting in such mode of usage.